# Specifying directory for checkout

Tags: maven

I'm not sure if the following is possible or not:

I have uploaded my Maven project `test-app` to my repository. I would now like to go onto a different machine and checkout this project from the repository so I can later build it. I enter the following onto the command line:

```
C:\projects\workspace\testproject>mvn scm:checkout -DconnectionUrl=repo.url
```

The project is correctly checked out, but the problem is instead of going to C:\projects\workspace\testproject\target it goes to C:\projects\workspace\testproject\${project.basedir}\target. I have tried setting the basedir using `-Dbasedir=C:\projects\workspace\testproject` but it does not change anything. Is there a way to specify the directory that checked-out project will go to? I am using Maven 3.0.3. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `-Dbasedir=.`

If that does not help, `scm:checkout` goal seems to have [checkoutDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/checkout-mojo.html#checkoutDirectory) parameter, which you can try using.

Also, you may want to look at [scm:bootstrap](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/examples/bootstrapping-with-pom.html) to build the project from a fresh copy of the source in the scm repository

Comment: Thank you so much! checkoutDirectory was indeed the parameter I was looking for. I am going to look at scm:bootstrap because it sounds like that might better suit my needs.